# input type image vs button with background-image

Tags: html, css, forms, user-interface

In a form which needs to have a image button which markup is better:
To create a `<input type="image">` and add the image as source, or create a button element and add the image as a background with CSS?

Until now I have used button with background-image as rarely seen `<input type="image">` used .
`<button>` is more friendly with mobile devices. But now I am thinking what if the image is deleted accidentally from the server? The button with the background-image would not be visible, but the input type image can uses the value as a fallback if the image is deleted.

Answer (score 2):

The HTML5 spec's [Image Button State documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#image-button-state-(type=image)) is a bit vague:

> The `input` element represents either an image **from which a user can select a coordinate and submit the form**, or alternatively a button from which the user can submit the form.

I *think* the intended use of the `type=image` `input` element is for selecting co-ordinates on an image, however I guess over time this was misused and is now accepted as just an input element with an image background. *However* in both cases it does state that the intended purpose of this button is to submit a form.

So in short:

1. If it isn't supposed to either submit a form or select co-ordinates on the image, use a `<button>` element;
2. If it's intended effect is to allow a user to select co-ordinates on the image, use the `<input>` element;
3. If it's intended effect is to submit a form, use either - this is a personal preference thing (I'd use a `<button>`, myself).

Answer (score 0):

Creating a button and adding a background to it will give you more flexibility in styling it

Answer (score 0):

You should try button with background. here is an example.

```html
<button></button>
<style>
button{background:url(http://www.used-car.com.au/images/small%20green%20button.jpg);height:70px;width:70px}
</style>
```